# How to initialize different classes of objects automatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, generic-programming

I want to make a class registry class that automatically makes a `UITableViewCell` and when the user presses the button it'll go to that class and run the code.

Currently to do something like that, in the view controller I have to do something like this

```
Function1Class *function = [[Function1Class alloc] init];
function.view.backgroundColor = [self veryLightGrayColor];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: menu animated: YES];
```

Then in the data source I make a new case in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and in the delegate I make a case in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` for a one line method call.

I'd like to change the code so anyone that wants to add a new class to this page can just do it at one place, something like:

```
Function1 *function;
[self addClass:function];
```

And in `addClass` the "function" passed in will be stored in an array

For the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` cases they can easily call the right methods by storing in an array.

The problem is how do I automate the initialization of each class object passed into `addClass`?

I could get the user to write code like this to add in their class

```
Function1 *function = [[Function1 alloc] init];
[self addClass:function];
```

Then the class object is already initialized, but that means during startup EVERY class object is getting initialized, which is a problem if there is a lot of classes. How can I take out a class object from the array, and then initialize it to use it? The class objects are all different classes, so I can't hardcode `arrayOfClassObjects[i] = [[Function1 alloc] init];`

Thanks

Comment: Can you use reflection? Something like `[[NSClassFromString(@"ClassNameOnlyKnownAtRuntime") alloc] init]`?

Comment: ^That might be very promising. Let me try that out.

Answer (score 1):

Classes are objects, so you can store the classes in an array:

```
NSArray *functions = @[ [Function1 class],
                        [Function2 class] ];
```

Then, when you want to instantiate one, you make it indirectly:

```
id instance = [[functions[0] alloc] init];
```

So your `addClass:` should be something like:

```
- (void)addClass:(Class)cls {
    [self.classList addObject:cls];
}
```